# I got an error about override method and class jsonresponse

Tags: java, android, json, class

I can't solve this problem in my new app. I am a beginner in Android Studio. My **register.java** class file is added here:

```
package com.agte.agtevivo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Register extends AppCompatActivity  {

Button button;
EditText editText3,editText4,editText5,editText6,editText7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

     editText3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
     editText5 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
     editText6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
     editText7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    //button.setOnClickListener(this);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       // @Override
         public void onClik(View v){

             final String name=editText3.getText().toString();
             final String username=editText4.getText().toString();
    final int      number=Integer.parseInt(editText7.getText().toString());
             final String shop=editText5.getText().toString();
             final String password=editText6.getText().toString();

Response.Listener<String> responceListener =new Response.Listener<String>(){
               //  @Override
                 public void onResponce (String responce){
                     try {
                         JSONObject jsonResponce =new JSONObject(responce);
             boolean success=new jsonResponce("Registerd Successfully");

                         if(success)
                         {
               Intent intent =new Intent(Register.this,Login.class);
                             Register.this.startActivity(intent);
                          }else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                             builder.setMessage("Register Failed");
                             //.setNegativeButton("Retry",null);
                             //.create()
                             //.show();
                         }
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 };


             };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest =new RegisterRequest
   (name,username,number,shop,password,responceListener);
             RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
             queue.add(registerRequest);
         }
     });
     }

  /* @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button:
    break;
   }

 }
*/
   }
```

I got an **error** I have listed on below:

> Error:(38, 62) error:  is not
>   abstract and does not override abstract method onClick(View)  in
>   OnClickListener
>
> Error:(48, 93) error:  is
>   not      abstract and does not override abstract  method
>   onResponse(String) in Listener
>
> Error:(53, 50) error: cannot find symbol class jsonResponce
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileFlavorDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the
>   compiler error output for details.

Currently I got an error:

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>()   {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                        boolean success = new jsonResponse.getBoolean("Success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
                            Register.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed");
                            //.setNegativeButton("Retry",null);
                            //.create()
                            //.show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

**Error** is:

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlavorDebugJavaWithJavac'.
  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
  Error:(62, 47) error: incompatible types
  required: boolean
  found:    getBoolean
```

Comment: it should be response and not responce

Comment: ya where will i change

Comment: change it as Response , not Responce. it is in your question's heading.

Comment: and also use "Response" in all over the code, not "Responce"

Comment: ya got it how to change other errors

Comment: Why you have commented @Override, it should be there so remove comments from it, as it should be override here

Comment: ya i removes that but same problem here

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.agte.agtevivo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Register extends AppCompatActivity  {

Button button;
EditText editText3,editText4,editText5,editText6,editText7;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

     editText3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
     editText4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
     editText5 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
     editText6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
     editText7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);

    button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    //button.setOnClickListener(this);

     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       // @Override
         public void onClick(View v){

             final String name=editText3.getText().toString();
             final String username=editText4.getText().toString();
    final int      number=Integer.parseInt(editText7.getText().toString());
             final String shop=editText5.getText().toString();
             final String password=editText6.getText().toString();

Response.Listener<String> responceListener =new Response.Listener<String>(){
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse (String responce){
                     try {
                         JSONObject jsonResponce =new JSONObject(responce);
             // What is this ?
                  boolean success=new jsonResponce("Registerd Successfully");

                         if(success)
                         {
               Intent intent =new Intent(Register.this,Login.class);
                             Register.this.startActivity(intent);
                          }else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
                             builder.setMessage("Register Failed");
                             //.setNegativeButton("Retry",null);
                             //.create()
                             //.show();
                         }
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                 };


             };
    RegisterRequest registerRequest =new RegisterRequest
   (name,username,number,shop,password,responceListener);
             RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Register.this);
             queue.add(registerRequest);
         }
     });
     }

  /* @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button:
    break;
   }

 }
*/
   }
```

Theres a load of grammar failures in your code, which I corrected in the snipped above (just make a diff) for further debugging look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: ya i got an error about   boolean success=new jsonResponce("Registerd Successfully");
this just fetch string from php

Comment: I tried the code I posted and there are no errors anymore, Exceptions were: your `onClick` Method was namen `onClik` you commented out the `@Override`, yout overriden Method `onResponce` must be namend `onResponse` and you have not a class named `jsonResponce` to you will not be able to instantiate this with new. Have you tried the code I posted above ? Leave the `new jsonResponce(...)` commented out for the first try

Comment: ya changed my code and i got error about success class when i leave the line =new jsonResponce("Registerd Successfully") .when i use that i got an  error about getboolean

Comment: Yes that is because your program do not know the class jsonResponce, you have to create a class jsonResponce with the desired behavior. What do you want to achieve with your jsonRespon**s**e call ?

Comment: how can i add register method using this class

Comment: ya sure sir am just create app with login and register that need to register with database and check password in login page and if true enter into new  page.So i have get more errors if you have free please help me to do that

Comment: am beginner in android\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118622/discussion-between-david-and-krishnaprasad-k-k).